# Cannot fetch photo from database using restful api

Tags: angularjs, post, web-applications, get, restful-url

Im trying to fetch photo of a particular userId which is stored in the database,
Im able to generate response from the API as shown:
[image]
 but it is received in the error part of the getPhotopath() method of controller as shown:
[image]
**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-3 " ng-init="modifyphoto()" >
            <img class="smaller" ng-src="fetchedimg" ng-model="fetchedimg"><br>
          <p>{{userName}}</p>
          <div ng-model="userType">
                 <p>{{userType | UserFilter}}</p>
          </div>
          <div ng-controller="AskController">
                 <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="gotouserdetails()">View
                       My Details</button>

          </div>
   </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.modifyphoto = function() {
          $scope.getPhotoPath();
          if($scope.userPhoto==null){
                 $scope.fetchedimg=$scope.defaultimg;
          }
          else{
                 $scope.fetchedimg=$scope.userPhoto;
          }
   };

   $scope.getPhotoPath = function() {

          var obj = JSON.parse($cookies.get('user'));
          $scope.passUserId = obj.userId;
          $http.get(URI + "user/getphoto"+"/"+$scope.passUserId).then(
                       function(response) {      
                              alert("hifrsegfsfgv");
                              alert(response.data.message);

                              $scope.userPhoto=response.data.userPhoto;
                       }, function(response) {
                              alert("hi");
                              alert(response.data);
                              $scope.userPhoto =null;
                              alert("danger"+response.data.userPhoto);
                       });
   };
```

**API:**

```
@Path("getphoto/{an}")
   @GET
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public Response getPhoto(@PathParam("an") String userId) throws Exception {
          String returnValue = null;
          Response response = null;
          User user = null;
          try {
                 System.out.println(userId);
                 UserService userService = Factory.createUserService();
                 String photoPath=userService.getPhotoPath(userId);
                 user = new User();
                 user.setUserPhoto(photoPath);
                 System.out.println(photoPath);
                 returnValue = JSONParser.toJson(user);
                 System.out.println(returnValue);
                 response = Response.status(Status.OK).entity(returnValue).build();
          } catch (Exception e) {
                 String errorMessage = AppConfig.PROPERTIES.getProperty(e.getMessage());
                 User user1 = new User();
                 user1.setMessage(errorMessage);
                 String returnString = JSONParser.toJson(user1);
                 response = Response.status(Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).entity(returnString).build();
          }
          return response;
   }
```

Im not understanding if the status is OK in backend then why it is recieved in the error part?

Comment: @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) your photo returned as JSON that's why you get the "invalid token" error

Answer (score 0):

Try returning your image in base64 format to avoid JSON Parse errors. and bind that image to the img tag

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: im fetching the path only from database the image is stored in local folder..i need to recieve the path string in the controller..

Comment: You can either convert your uploaded image from bytes to base 64 string and store it in database as a string and retrieve it without any parsing  or you can convert your binary data to base 64 string  for example 

var testData = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07};

var inputStream = new MemoryStream(testData);

var inputAsString = Convert.ToBase64String(inputStream.ToArray());

Comment: If you are only fetching the path from database then make sure your path is absolute i.e. it should point to the application folder having the local image files.